# AWS CodeBuild start command with ENV variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS codebuild where I want to start gradle project

My buildspec.yml file

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "$THREADS_NUMBER"
      - echo "$TAGS"
      - echo ./gradlew cucumber --tags "\"$TAGS\"" --threads "$THREADS_NUMBER"
      - ./gradlew cucumber --tags "\"${TAGS}\"" --threads ${THREADS_NUMBER}
```

I can see that $THREADS_NUMBER is 4 and $TAGS is xxx.

Same with

```
Running command echo ./gradlew cucumber --tags "\"$TAGS\"" --threads "$THREADS_NUMBER"
./gradlew cucumber --tags "not @my" --threads 4
```

But starting gradle makes me problem

```
- ./gradlew cucumber --tags "\"${TAGS}\"" --threads ${THREADS_NUMBER}

Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: ./gradlew cucumber --tags "\"${TAGS}\"" --threads ${THREADS_NUMBER}. Reason: exit status 1
```

Error above:

```
> Task :processTestResources
> Task :testClasses
Exception in thread "main" io.cucumber.tagexpressions.TagExpressionException: Syntax error. Expected operator
    at io.cucumber.tagexpressions.TagExpressionParser.check(TagExpressionParser.java:127)
    at io.cucumber.tagexpressions.TagExpressionParser.parse(TagExpressionParser.java:65)
    at cucumber.runtime.filter.TagPredicate.<init>(TagPredicate.java:28)
    at cucumber.runtime.filter.Filters.<init>(Filters.java:24)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.build(Runtime.java:245)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:24)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
> Task :cucumber FAILED
```

I don't understand why ${THREADS_NUMBER} and ${TAGS} are not replaced. I try also without brackets but is the same...

Any ideas?

Comment: You are escaping the qoutes in your commands. Don't think you need to do that.

Comment: I think the variables are not printed because it's the ci telling you which line is wrong. Aside from the escaped qoutes I don't think the syntax is wrong. Something else is. Does this work locally?

Comment: I am getting "Exception in thread "main" io.cucumber.tagexpressions.TagExpressionException: Syntax error. Expected operator"

Comment: Working fine if I am not using ENV variables